# Windows App Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 App in Javascript and HTML5. While running it in the emulator I am getting the following error:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'.

It is highlighting to the below line of code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#CommentForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Will be great if some one can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Have you included the validate library?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Are you taalking about jquery.validate.min.js. Then yes i have included it in header.

Comment: refer http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation as there is no built-in jQuery function named validate. It's available from several plugins though. For example

Comment: @AnilKumar I am using validate plugin. and i have included jquery.validate.min.js in my project.

Comment: @DilipKumarYadav can you move your code " $("#CommentForm").validate(" to document.ready and revert back with the behaviour?